# how to export mySQL table where there's a matching value

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with a table with different fields.. Lets say some of them are good, normal, bad labelled at some point in database.

Is it possible, I can export all good field rows only?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. Can you elaborate on your definition of "good, normal and bad". An actual structure of the table would be nice as well  (only relevant columns should be enough) , preferably with some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: By "export" do you just mean dump the data to a file?

Comment: Hi, sorry if it wasn't clear. By export I mean, that export it from server and downloading it on computer. Like backing it up, you know what I am trying to say? Like you download a backup of a website from MySQL to computer as SQL file.

Comment: As for the good, normal or bad. please see this image [link](http://imgur.com/LVC3uSt) .  Look at the 'answer3' db fields.. I want to extract all the rows with 'happy' attribute.. Let me know if I am making sense or not, else I'll try to explain again. sorry, i am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to select the rows by selecting one by one or by querying. if you want all record with "good" then you have select all this record either with select query of select one by one with clicking.

then you have to export from the bottom "Export" button not from the main menu export.

See the image it will help you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Limx2.png)